# How to run 2 Reactjs apps in one Webapp in Portal Azure?

Tags: reactjs, azure-web-app-service, vite

I'm trying to deploy 2 ReactJs app to WebApp service in portal azure, but facing issue that only default app (/ path) working fine, the remaining app (/admin) not working.
Both of the apps using Vite Reactjs, in vite.config.js of each app

- base: '/' this is customer app
- base: '/admin' this is admin app

Both apps worked fine in local, issue only occurs when deploying them to one web app. I'm using web app (window host) with Virtual applications and directories directory

- '/' pointed to /customer_portal
- /admin' pointed to /admin_portal

With this config, Customer portal works good, but admin project has issue, only route /admin work, other endpoints like /admin/login will not work, it will render customer_portal app with NoPageFound. Any solutions?

I doubted web.config of mine, but I didn't find any solution yet, my `web.config` at root directory: [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-grothendieck-69pk58?file=/web.config)
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found myself solution, change web.config like this will work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Customer Portal">
                    <match url="^(?!admin/).*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                      <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/admin/" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Admin Portal">
                    <match url="^(admin/).*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                      <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/admin/" negate="false" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/admin/index.html" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```